# Что такое поток?

Tags: c#, потоки-данных, терминология

Хочу понять что такое поток, может кто то видел историю которая объясняет как работает поток или может навести пример с жизни

Comment: Имеется в виду `stream`? Именно это `поток данных`. Или всё же `thread` - `поток выполнения`?

Answer (score 3):

Вы хотите историю про поток данных? Извольте.

Представьте себе, что у вас есть колбаса. И вы можете от этой колбасы отрезать кусочек. Потом ещё кусочек. Если вы голодный, то кусочек побольше. Или можете какое-то время не отрезать, ну или передать остаток колбасы другому человеку.

Так вот, потоки данных ведут себя так же. В начале у вас есть целый поток, вы можете <s>отрезать от него кусочек</s> прочитать из него порцию данных и <s>съесть</s> обработать, ну или выбросить. Вы можете потом читать ещё данные. Вы можете в недо<s>еденном</s>читанном состоянии передать поток другому куску кода, чтобы он его читал и обрабатывал дальше. И так вы делаете, пока поток не окончится.

Comment: кхм, кхм. Ну и аналогия.

Comment: @Igor: У вас найдётся лучше метафора? Пишите альтернативный ответ! :-)

Comment: Перефразируя Бернарда Шоу: "Если у меня есть батон колбасы и у Вас есть батон колбасы, и мы обменяемся этими колбасами, то у каждого из нас останется по одному батону колбасы."

Comment: @Igor: Перефразируя известную мудрость с Пикабу, зато если у вас есть метафора, и у меня есть метафора, и мы ими обменяемся, то у каждого из нас станет по две метафоры!

Comment: Так это же вторая половина цитаты Шоу!

Comment: @Igor: Именно! Но её так затаскали, что о настоящем авторе уже никто не помнит.